# Javascript JSON woes

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following code to get me some information from my database:

```
  const getDeviceUID = `SELECT Device_UID FROM Device WHERE ThingName = "${deviceName}"`;

  const deviceUIDResult = await new Promise((resolve) => {
    connection.query(getDeviceUID, (err, results, fields) => {
       if (err) return resolve(false);
       resolve(results);
     });
  });
```

I'm assuming (I'm pretty new to this!) that deviceUIDResult is now a JSON object as when I do this:

```
console.log("RES: " + JSON.stringify(deviceUIDResult));
```

I get the following:

```
RES: [{"Device_UID":"xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"}]
```

But when I try to parse it:

```
  deviceUIDObj = JSON.parse(deviceUIDResult)
```

I get this:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
```

And when I try to extract my field:

```
var myField = deviceUIDResult["Device_UID"];
```

it tells me that its undefined.
What am I not understanding here?

Comment: *"What am I not understanding here?"* `JSON.parse` takes in a string containing JSON and converts it to native JavaScript value. `deviceUIDResult` is already a JavaScript array.

Comment: You don't need to parse it, in other words.

Comment: Also your Promise callback should have *two* parameters, the second being the `reject()` link. Call that when `err` is non-empty instead of `resolve()`.

Comment: Also, check your database API because it's likely the case that `connection.query()` can itself return a Promise, and if so you don't need to make your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`deviceUIDResult` is a JavaScript array containing one object.  Note the square braces:

```
indicates an array 
↓
[{"Device_UID":"xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"}]
 ↑
 indicates an object
```

So, get the first object in the array first: `var myField = deviceUIDResult[0]["Device_UID"];`